# Django: Does .count() force the queryset evaluation

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-database

I want to pass a queryset which involves counting rows to a function without calling the database right away. For example, the following queryset is lazy and does not access the database until it is evaluated:

```py
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
```

I know from [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) that `len()` forces the evaluation but what about `count()`? Does this hit the database right away?

```py
queryset = MyModel.objects.all().count()
```

**EDIT**: I clarified my question

Comment: What do you mean by "*a non evaluated count queryset*"?

Comment: what will be the purpose of the queryset? can you add more code to describe what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will answer your query.

> A `count()` call performs a `SELECT COUNT(*)` behind the scenes, so you
> should always use `count()` rather than loading all of the record into
> Python objects and calling `len()` on the result (unless you need to
> load the objects into memory anyway, in which case `len()` will be
> faster).
>
> Note that if you want the number of items in a QuerySet and are also
> retrieving model instances from it (for example, by iterating over
> it), **it’s probably more efficient to use `len(queryset)` which won’t
> cause an extra database query like `count()` would.**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#count

Comment: Slightly off-piste from the original question, but interestingly the docs now explain a further nuance: `If the queryset has already been fully retrieved, count() will use that length rather than perform an extra database query` so `.count()` doesn't always hit the db. However if you used `.iterator()` over the queryset (rather than fully evaluating it) then the cache doesn't get filled in, so `.count()` will hit the database in that case.

Comment: can you include the docs link in comment?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#count (I can't edit the above comment any more)